# QGIS/ArcGIS projection problem between ESPG:4616 and ESPG:30165

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I have two layers, one in ESPG:4616 (JGD2000) and one in ESPG:30165 (Tokyo, Japan Plane Rectangular CS V). In QGIS, layer are not matching as you can see below.

[image]

I tried everything in QGIS, modifying the project projection, with and without "on the fly", recording the layers in another coordinate system, etc. At this point, I through that the problem came from the data.

However, when I open both the layers in ArcGIS, the software do an automatic transformation (one projection into one another) and layers are matching as you can see below.

[image]

At this point I am lost, I even tried to record both the layers in a brand new projection in ArcGIS, still layers are not matching in QGIS.

Here is a link with a small sample of both layers

[Dropbox file](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/s2e0a6ly1xop7bk/AABzjcwt4oz9FFeDsGlAuc-Ka?dl=0)

UPDATE:

ArcGIS also has a problem, when I add a basemap, we can see that both layers are not overlapping

[image]

While using open layer in QGIS, one layer is overlapping the background map.

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm that when you go into the layer properties, that they both are using the appropriate CRS? i.e. that when importing the layers, another has accidentally been selected

Comment: It seems that the building layer is correct, but the roads layer is really in `Tokyo` datum, `EPSG:4301` instead of `EPSG:4612`.

Comment: I did several tries with ESPG:4616, ESPG:30165 and with WGS84. The only time data are overlapping is in ARCGIS with two different CRS, But yet it does not matches the basemap.

Comment: I echo @AndreJ 's comment. Usually Tokyo and JGD2000 has ~400m shift. Changing CRS of roads to `EPSG:4301` by `Define current projection` tool has fixed it in my QGIS 2.18.13 environment.

Comment: I also think you have overwritten the .prj file, which is not "manually displace the Road layer"

Comment: Note: In ArcGIS Desktop, in ArcMap, geographic/datum transformations are not applied automatically. They are in ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: Thanks you @Kazuhito, I didn't knew this difference. It works now

Comment: Thanks for the update @ePoQ that's great. Just an additional note; Changing CRS to `EPSG:4301` is usually good enough but you may see small discrepancy (about several meters) which comes from local distortion. If you need more accuracy please consider trying [TKY2JGD](http://www.gsi.go.jp/sokuchikijun/tky2jgd.html).

Comment: @Kazuhito, my japanese is a bit limited but I will give it a try. Thank you for the link

Comment: @ePoQ  It has terminated in June. Please visit [TKY2JGD](http://vldb.gsi.go.jp/sokuchi/surveycalc/tky2jgd/main.html) website (in Japanese) instead. My double apologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you have wrongly overwritten the Coordinate Reference System (CRS) file of one or both of the layers. This information is stored in the .prj file.

I have no idea how Arcgis handles this, but Qgis uses them to define the CRS of a layer, so if there is a .prj file, QGIS will use it.

You can change the CRS for each layer in the layers panel, but if you want to ammend or restore a worng CRS info in the .prj file, then you have to do what @Kazuhito said in the comments: `Vector` `Data management Tools` `Define current projection` as in the pictures below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Update for those reading this post later. I indeed did the mistake of wrongly write the wrong projection within the .prj file of my road layer and the answers provided above resolved my problem.

Yet, as explained here [Basemap / shapefile not overlapping](https://community.esri.com/thread/101790) the basemap layer within ArcGIS is enable to overlap with some specific projections. And, as a matter of fact, my road layer didn't had any projection file encoded but the automatic transformation process within ArcGIS can set the projection of a layer based on another layer. By doing that, I generated the gap within the above screenshot myself by recording for the first time my layer with no projection while the non-overlapping basemap was open in background.